# Neo4j spatial import error

Tags: import, neo4j, openstreetmap, spatial

I have recently started using neo4j spatial. I wish to run the import OSM class to store its info in a neo4j database using Neo4j spatial. However I am getting an error in the final step.

I've done the following steps (using cygwin on windows):

downloaded maven, setup the home path with export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
installed jdk 7, java_home defined

```
git clone git://github.com/neo4j/spatial.git 
cd spatial 
mvn clean install
```

This takes a while to complete, but it gets there eventually.

Next:

`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` which seems to suceed.

Then I try to open the main method from the command line:

```
java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* org.neo4j.gis.spatial.osm.OSMImporter osm-db two-street.osm
```

and I get this:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.gis.spatial.osm.OSMImporter

Did I miss something here? I'm not very familiar with unix or maven in general, but this seems to be some sort of dependency issue?

Comment: you'll need to bundle a jar with all dependencies. look into the target directory if there is a "xy-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Replace the colon in

```
target/classes:target/dependency/*
```

with a semicolon

```
target/classes;target/dependency/*
```

I was running into the same problem until I actually checked the command line options for Java - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html